# Сохранить состояние полей во фрагменте android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент, который содержит Spinner'ы и EditText'ы. Пользователь их заполняет и затем переходит на другой фрагмент для произведения некоторых действий там. Когда он возвращается обратно на первый фрагмент с данными из frag2, нужно восстановить или записать программно то, что было им введено ранее.

Делаю так:

**Фрагмент 1**

в onCreateView

```
Bundle bdReStore = getArguments();
if (bdReStore != null) {
     String fs = bdReStore.getString("editTemp");
     Log.i(LOG_TAG, "recieve: " + editTemp);
     editTemp.setText(fs);
}
```

в коде перехода на frag2 (onClick реализован)

```
Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
Bundle bundleStore = new Bundle();
if (addTask.getText().length() != 0) { 
   bundleStore.putString("editTemp", editTemp.getText().toString();); /** сохранить строку, если введена */ 
}
frag1.setArguments(bdReStore);
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
 .replace(R.id.content_frame, frag2).commit();
```

**Фрагмент 2**

```
Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("tag", toothCount);
frag1.setArguments(bundle);
android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame,  frag1).commit();
```

Думаю, что проблема во втором фрагменте (frag2), когда возвращаюсь на первый. Потому что здесь приходится создавать заново новый экземпляр frag1. Поэтому и **null** мне выводится в LogCat.

**Вопрос:**
Что нужно изменить в коде, чтобы реализовать идею?

**Предложение:** 
Была мысль сделать **хардкод**: передать из frag1 во frag2, а потом обратно из frag2 во frag1. Но думаю, что есть более гуманный способ.

**myUpdate 01**
Часть моего кода, которая сейчас есть рабочей.О ней я писал выше: http://pastebin.com/6cz1BL98

Comment: @web_alex скорее всего он у вас дестроится. Попробуйте добавлять фрагмент в стек `addToBackStack()`.

Comment: @monomi, при переходе из frag1 на frag2 прописать 
.addToBackStack(null);
и все ?

Comment: Попробуйте setRetainInstance(true) у фрагмента.

Comment: @monomi, не помогло.(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь, но в целом ваши предложения мне не помогли. Добавить в BackStack, а потом из него вытащить фрагмент я не смог. Увы, но по вашим советам ничего не вышло. Но все равно спасибо за отзывчивость. Я решил применить собственную идею, которую считаю правильной и разумной.

**Подытожим:**

*1. Требуемые действия:*

- Сохранить введенные/выбранные ранее данные во фрагменте и восстановить их после возвращения на фрагмент.

*2. Действия, которые будут выполнены пользователем:*

- Введены данные в editText1, выбран элемент spinner'a spin1.
- Выполнен переход на другой фрагмент frag2, произведены на нем действия, после которых пользователь возвращается на первоначальный фрагмент frag1.

*3.Код, который я применил:*

- **для frag1:**

  ```
  EditText edit1;
  Spinner spin1;

  @Override    
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag1, container, false);
       edit1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       spin1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spiiner1);

  /** в теле одного из onClick получаю значения из edit1 и spin1 */
  // в onClick добавляю метод, в котором все будет происходить. Мне так удобнее

  getAndSave();

  /** bundle from Frag2() */
  Bundle bdReStoreRx = getArguments();
  if (bdReStoreRx != null) {
      // создаем переменную строку и сохраняем в нее значение из Bundle(). Затем записываем/назначаем его в edit1.
      String edit1Temp = bdReStoreRx.getString("edit1Temp"); edit1.setText(edit1Temp);
      // создаем переменную целое значение и сохраняем в нее значение позиции spinner'a. Затем назначаем его.
      Integer spin1Temp = bdReStoreRx.getInt("spin1Temp"); spin1.setSelection(spin1Temp);
  }

  return rootView;

  }

  public void getAndSave() {    
        Bundle bdReStoreTx = new Bundle();    
        /** сохранить строку из edit1, если введена */

        if (edit1.getText().length() != 0) { bdReStoreTx.putString("edit1Temp", edit1.getText().toString()); }

  /** сохранить выбранный элемент в spin1 */    
  Integer spin1_SelectedId = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition(); bdReStoreTx.putInt("spin1Temp", spin1_SelectedId);

  Frag2 frag2 = new Frag2();
  frag2.setArguments(bdReStoreTx);    
  android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();    
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction()    
  .replace(R.id.content_frame, frag2).commit();
  }
  ```
- **для frag2:**

String edit1Temp;
    Integer spin1Temp;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_frag2, container, false);

    // в теле onClick фрагмента frag2 будет метод sendData();

}

public void sedData() {
Bundle bdReStoreTx = getArguments();
/** сохранить строку addTask, если введена */
if (bdReStoreTx != null) {
    edit1Temp = bdReStoreTx.getString("edit1Temp");
    spin1Temp = bdReStoreTx.getInt("spin1Temp");
}

Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();

Bundle bdReStoreRx* = new Bundle();
/** from frag1 */
    bdReStoreRx.putString("adit1Temp", edit1Temp);
    bdReStoreRx.putInt("spin1Temp", spin1Temp);
/** from frag2 - данные, чтобы нужно передать из frag2 в frag1. Код приема tCo, sStrings в frag1 не рассматривается в данном вопросе, но ниже передача приведена */
    bdReStoreRx.putInt("tCo", tCo);
    bdReStoreRx.putStringArrayList("checkT", sStrings);
    frag1.setArguments(bdReStoreRx);
/** */
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame,  frag1).commit();
}
```

---

- При помощи **bdReStoreTx** передаем данные из frag1 во frag2.
- При помощи **bdReStoreRx** передаем данные из frag2 во frag1 (возвращаем обратно то, что было во frag1 вместе с тем, что взято из frag2.
- Возможно, кто-то назовет приведенный код странным или некорректным, но мне на это все равно, так как код работает. Цель достигнута. Пользуйтесь им, если нужно.
- P.S.: Если найдете ошибки в коде, то пишите. Буду править. Приведенный выше код писал с головы. Мог где-то допустить ошибку следующего типа, нужно "spin1Temp", а написал "spinTemp" и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что ваша проблема в том, что состояние сохранять надо не в аргументах фрагмента, а вот так

```
public class FragmentBase extends Fragment
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,null);

        //Если у вас базовый фрагмент создает View, то делаете так
        //View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

        //тут делаете что надо
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            //были сохраненные состояния, надо восстановить
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
    {
        //тут пишете необходимые вещи в outState
        if(outState == null)
            outState = new Bundle();
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**  [Исходники рабочего примера](https://github.com/rovkinmax/ExampleFragmentSaveInstance/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/fragmentsaveinstance)

Comment: Я в onCreateView дописал код выше, но после запуска на экране ничего не отобразилось. Возможно, я чего-то не знаю, но создал я в этом методе View, на который посадил все свои виджеты. А после вызова return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); я не знаю, как вызвать свой rootView.

Comment: @web_alex обновил ответ.

Comment: @Andreich, при первой инициализации приложении вылетает. У себя приложении я создаю фрагмент по xml-слою, который вставляю в контейнер. View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_layout, container, false);
Затем инициализирую объекты со слоя и алгоритм работы.

Comment: @web_alex я не понимаю, в чем ваша проблема.
Вот вам рабочий пример того, как передавать данные между фрагментами туда и обратно.   
Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

У вас, если я правильно понял ваш код, 3 ошибки:

1. При замене 1-го фрагмента вторым 1-й не добавляется в память `FragmentManager` методом `addToBackStack(null)` (надо до `commit(`) в `transaction` вызвать).
2. Во втором фрагменте надо бы не новый 1-й фрагмент создавать, а старый по ID находить и ему уже передавать через сеттер или аргументы данные.
3. Вы аргументы в коде второго фрагмента (Bundle) передаёте какому-то `"addNewTask_fragment"`, а в трансакцию отдаёте новый экземпляр 1-го фрагмента... Чего вы ожидаете от этого кода?

Итого: Как минимум присваивайте аргументы правильным экземплярам фрагментов.

**Обновление 0:**

Замените:

```
Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1();
```

на

```
Frag1 frag1 = (Frag1)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yours_fragment_container);
```

Далее нам нужен сеттер в первом фрагменте:

```
public void setMyValue(int value)
{
this.myValue=value;
}
```

Возвращаемся ко второму фрагменту. После нахождения первого и проверки его на "null" присваиваем его полю нужное значение:

```
frag1.setMyValue(value);
```

Теперь 1-й фрагмент получил нужное значение нашего поля, и можно его призвать на экран:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.yours_fragment_container,  frag1).commit();
```

**Обновление 1:**

Итого:

1. У вас не реализовано сохранение и восстановление данных в первом фрагменте.
2. Заменяя первый фрагмент вторым, вы не сохраняете первый фрагмент во FragmentManager().
3. Со второго фрагмента вы не вызываете старый, а создаёте новый который, естественно, пуст.

Выводы:

1) в первом фрагменте надо сохранять переменные так:

```
public class FragmentBase extends Fragment
{
//Переменные, которые надо сохранить
String myString;
int myInt;

    @Override
    public View onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        //здесь восстанавливаем сохранённые переменные.
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            //восстанавливаем
this.myString=savedInstanceState.getString("myStringKey");
this.myInt=savedInstanceState.geInt("myIntKey");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//Сохраняем данные
outState.putString("myStringKey", this.myString);
outState.putInt("myIntKey", this.myInt);

    }
}
```

2) вызывая второй фрагмент, не забывайте добавить первый в FragmentManager:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,  frag2);
transaction.commit();
```

3) во втором фрагменте вызывайте сохранённый 1-й фрагмент с сохранённым состоянием:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment1 frag1=fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,  frag1);
transaction.commit();
```

И последнее, **но не по важности**:

*Все эти вопросы обычно и не возникают, если прочитать хотя бы одну книгу по Андроид, а если и возникают, то решаются гуглом за 5 минут. Вы вряд ли научитесь программировать, если будете решать отдельные проблемы в коде на форумах, а не изучать архитектуру и доки.*

Comment: @Andreich, 
по п.2 - поможете с кодом ? 
по п.3 - "addNewTask_fragment" вылез случайно. Я для простоты кода назвал фрагменты frag1 и frag2.

Comment: @web_alex, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Andreich, что-то совсем не уловил идею. Зачем мне из 1-го передавать во второй? Мне нужно сохранить то, что было в первом, чтобы опять отобразить в первом. А получилось так, что я передаю из 2-го в первый. Такую передачу я делал при помощи bundle, все работало отлично.

Comment: @web_alex, обновил ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, android я изучаю последовательно. Только начал работать с фрагментами. И в книгах примитивные примеры, которые размножены по сайтам и везде без детальных описаний. Поэтому учусь как могу. 

Я обновил вопрос. Добавил ссылку на оригинальный код.

Comment: @web_alex, я сам с фрагментами мутить начал недели 3 назад. Один раз прочитав книгу +гугл. Мне этого более чем хватило.

И зачем вы добавили ссылку на код, который за все эти часы (с момента задания вопроса) никак не поменялся? Что вы пробовали сделать из предложенных решений? Что пошло не так? Неужели вы хотите, что бы мы вам тут готовый код под вашу задумку выдали? 

Расскажите таки что вы попробовали и что получили.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, никогда я не просил что-то делать за меня! Код я дал, чтобы было видно, что я имею изначально. Что получилось, а что нет? Все неполучилось. Сейчас внес Ваш код себе в проект. Приложение крашится на строке 
`transaction.replace(R.layout.layout_frag2,  frag2);`.
Пишет, что его нет: NullPointerException.

@ЮрийСПб, контейнер (R.id.content_frame, но, если ввести его в replace, то выводит ошибку -  один и тот же, слои разные (/res/layout/..)

Comment: @web_alex, очевидно, что в данном случае вы не объявили и/или не проинициализировали 2-ой фрагмент. 
К тому же, у вас, похоже, разные контейнеры для разных фрагментов. А приведённый мною код работает для одного контейнера для обоих фрагментов.

Метод replace() работает **только** в случае, если оба фрагмента добавляются в один и тот же контейнер.